# Undefined index: Error in ajax POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im new on php programming and I get this error when i try to add a record on my table using ajax POST
: Undefined index: jour in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\server.php on line 6
and the same thing for other variables

here is my server.php page :

```
 <?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbgestion', 'root', '');
$page = isset($_GET['p'])? $_GET['p'] : '';
if($page=='add'){
    try{
        $jour = $_POST['jour'];
        $ventes = $_POST['ventes'];
        $soldeinitial = $_POST['soldeinitial'];
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO jours VALUES(?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$jour);
        $stmt->bindParam(2,$ventes);
        $stmt->bindParam(3,$soldeinitial);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            print "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Data has been added</div>";
        } else{
            print "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Failed to add data</div>";
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    } 
}
```

and here my html page :

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="40">Jour</th>
                            <th>Ventes</th>
                            <th>Solde Initial</th>
                            <th width="100">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <form id="sidebar">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="jour">Jour</label>
                        <input type="date" id="jour" name="jour" class="form-control" placeholder="jour"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ventes">Ventes</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ventes" name="ventes" class="form-control" placeholder="ventes"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="soldeinitial">Solde initial</label>
                        <input type="text" id="soldeinitial" name="soldeinitial" class="form-control" placeholder="soldeinitial"/>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveData()">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" id="update" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="updateData()">Update</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and finally this is my script.js file

```
function saveData(){
    var jour = $('#jour').val()
    var ventes = $('#ventes').val()
    var soldeinitial = $('#soldeinitial').val()
       $.post('server.php?p=add', {jour:jour, ventes:ventes, soldeinitial:soldeinitial}, function(data){
            viewData()
            $('#jour').val(' ')
            $('#ventes').val(' ')
            $('#soldeinitial').val(' ')
        })
    }
```

Comment: In your browsers dev tools network tab, can you see and redirects? Can you see the data being sent to the PHP page? Is it JSON or is it getting encoded as form data?

Comment: It seems like `'jour'` is not a valid index of the `$_POST` variable, You can print the contents of `$_POST` using `var_dump($_POST);`. This might help the debugging process.

Comment: Thanks for yours answers, the problem is resolved when i just change the name of the ids and names in inputs controls with different names than the database